# Microdata markup for a chemical substance?

Tags: schema.org, microdata, structured-data

I'm trying to add Microdata markup to a table of properties of a chemical substance. Below is a sample of some of the properties of one of the chemical substances I'm trying to markup.

[image: Sample of chemical properties]

I'm not exactly sure how to use the Microdata format, but right now I'm trying to use `Intangible` for the substance itself, and `PropertyValueSpecification` for the individual properties.

Anyway, I think I'm doing it wrong since [Google's testing tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) is giving me a separate `Intangible` and `PropertyValueSpecification`'s. I had expected that the `PropertyValueSpecification`'s would be children of the `Intangible`?

[image: Google Testing Tool result]

Comment: What is the purpose of doing so?   Micro data is useful when you know that a computer program will take the data from your website and do something useful for you.   I don't know of any consumers of the data you are providing.   Unless somebody has asked for the markup I wouldn't try to use it.   It is a common misconception, but there is no general SEO benefit for finding some markup to use on your site.

Answer (score 1):

Nesting HTML elements doesn’t affect Microdata unless you are using `itemprop`.

Here you have two Microdata items, not related in any way:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://example.com/Example">
  <span itemscope itemtype="http://example.com/Example">
  </span>
</div>
```

Here you have two Microdata items, connected via the `example` property:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://example.com/Example">
  <span itemprop="example" itemscope itemtype="http://example.com/Example">
  </span>
</div>
```

So you have to find suitable properties in Schema.org to connect items. For example, [`author`](http://schema.org/author) to connect a `Book` to a `Person`.

---

In your case:

The [`Intangible`](http://schema.org/Intangible) type (which, by the way, doesn’t seem to be appropriate for *substances*) doesn’t provide a property that takes a [`PropertyValueSpecification`](http://schema.org/PropertyValueSpecification) item as value. I don’t think that `PropertyValueSpecification` is a suitable type anyway. Instead, [`PropertyValue`](http://schema.org/PropertyValue) seems to be appropriate, which can be added (for example) to a `Product` via the [`additionalProperty`](http://schema.org/additionalProperty) property. Now the question is if it makes sense to represent your substances as products.

You might find more suitable types in the [health-lifesci extension](http://health-lifesci.schema.org/). For example, they define the [`Substance`](http://health-lifesci.schema.org/Substance) type:

> Any matter of defined composition that has discrete existence, whose origin may be biological, mineral or chemical.

But it has a medical background, and it seems to miss a way to add a `PropertyValue` (or similar) item. If you think `Product` can be appropriate, you could use both types together:

```html
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Substance http://schema.org/Product">
  <div itemprop="additionalProperty" itemtype="http://schema.org/PropertyValue">
    <!-- … -->
  </div>
</article>
```

---

Schema.org is not intended to go into detail for all possible domains, so you might want to consider [to find](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12098901/1591669) a domain-specific vocabulary/ontology.

As scientific domains like chemistry are typically strong in the [Linked Data](https://www.w3.org/standards/semanticweb/data) world, you might also want to consider to use [RDFa instead of Microdata](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25888436/1591669). The example from above could be marked up as:

```html
<article typeof="schema:Substance schema:Product">
  <div property="schema:additionalProperty" typeof="schema:PropertyValue">
    <!-- … -->
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: It seems like a big limitation that I can't add name/value properties of an arbitrary "thing" using microdata... I could perhaps use Product, but wouldn't it be "abusing" the Product category? I mean it's not really a physical product that is for sale or anything, just a "fact sheet" of a chemical substance, which seems more like something "intangible" or a "thing"...

Comment: @BadCash: I think this is an intentional decision from Schema.org, as they want to prevent that people come up with various custom properties (which typically aren’t useful for consumers) for everything. -- Regarding `Product`: It’s somewhat subjective. For it to be a `Product`, you don’t *have* to offer it for sale (for which there is the separate `Offer` type), but it should be something that *in principle* could be offered for sale. But I agree, it’s not a good match. I don’t understand your domain very much, but I’d bet that you can find a vocabulary that provides properties you need.

Comment: What about [ProductModel](http://schema.org/ProductModel)? The description says _"A datasheet or vendor specification of a product (in the sense of a prototypical description)."_, and I guess I can use `additionalProperty` for other than the substance ID and name?

Comment: @BadCash: Yes, `ProductModel` might be appropriate (it would be a more specific `Product`). And yes, you can use `additionalProperty` for every property for which there is no suitable property defined (`name` for the names, `identifier` for the IDs, maybe `description` for the comment).